# Asp.Net MVC with Kendo UI Grid Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create BranchType using BranchTypeViewModel.I am using Kendo MVC UI PopUp Grid to create My BranchTypes.

Here is codes:

**BranchTypeModel.cs**

```
public class BranchType
{

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] 
    public int BranchTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Branş tipi alanı girişi zorunludur!")]
    [DisplayName("Branş Tipi")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] 
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; } 
}
```

**BranchTypeViewModel.cs**

```
public class BranchTypeViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int BranchTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Branş Tipi")]
    public string BranchType { get; set; }


    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is My Repository CreateBranchType Function**

```
    public void CreateBranchType(BranchTypeViewModel branchType)
    {

        var entity = new BranchType();

        entity.BranchTypeId = branchType.BranchTypeId;
        entity.Type = branchType.BranchType;

        context.BranchTypes.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();

        branchType.BranchTypeId = entity.BranchTypeId;

    }
```

**Here is My Controller CreateBranchType Function**

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult CreateBranchType([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,BranchTypeViewModel branchType)
    {

        if (branchType != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.CreateBranchType(branchType);
        }


        return Json(new[] { branchType }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
```

**Here is My BranchType View**

```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI



@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Domain.Entities.BranchTypeViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.BranchType);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.BranchTypeId))
        .Create(update => update.Action("CreateBranchType", "Admin"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadBranchType", "Admin"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditBranchType", "Admin"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("DestroyBranchType", "Admin"))
    )
)
)
```

Problem is that when try to create branch type branchtype returns null and repository CreateBranchType function return exception like this:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So problem is CreateBranchTypeView model is not instantianeted.

I rreferenced [kendo mvc ui popup grid example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup)  to create this.

How can I Solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you debug the repository's `CreateBranchType` function. What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Ok.I solved this.Thanks by your interest